# Drupal 7 - Send automatically email to users who have the same interest than in new node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, subscription, drupal-rules

Okay, here's the deal. My client posts job ads to his website. Applicants can register in his page and choose what kind of jobs they're interested in. If new job ad (new node) includes same interest(s) than a user(applicant) has chosen, email should be sent automatically to the user(applicant).

I am building the site in Drupal 7 and tried to solve this with Rules. Problem is that I couldn't find a replacement pattern to scope all users, only current user was available. Email should be sent to all users who have the same interest(s) than in new job ad.

Could someone give some tips?

Answer (score 2):

What about using subscription module to achieve this: http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions

You can create different type to taxonomy terms like c, c++, java, testing, iOs etc & ask user to subscribe his interest.

Then on posting a job with x term, all the related users will receive an email. 
There are lot of other customization which you can achieve with this module.

Comment: It didn't work with Subscription module. Any other solutions?

Is it possible to use Entityfieldquery to get users who has same interest than in new node and then send mass email to all of them?

Comment: Hi, why do you not try to create an action rule in a custom module ?